# Django Migration Problems on production server

Tags: python, django, migration

Hi I would like to move my local environment to my production website but when I do makemigrations i get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "structure_structurefields" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "structure_structurefields"."seo_keywords" FROM "structure...
```

what do I do ? any help will be welcomed.

Comment: did you also run migrate?

Comment: Yes I did, the thing is it is a new database and also have relations  between my models. not sure how to migrate on a new database without running in this issue.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VCfJbEK9   here is my traceback

Comment: try and reset your migrations and start from scratch

Comment: no still not, because the structure table does not exist its picking up an issue

Comment: Why there is a query inside urls.py `for structure in StructureFields.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).order_by('order'):` ?